# Delete by word not by character using Computers Keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a textarea in my site. I have a word:

```
(e.g.)
    sampleword
```

I want to delete the word by words and not by character.

```
Output:
    ''
Incorrect Output:
    ampleword
```

UPDATE 1:

Below is the image of my textarea:

[image]

I want to delete the whole word using the `Delete` button in the keyboard.

Incorrect Output:

[image]

Correct Output:

[image]

How will I do that? What technology shall I use?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

As found in the example:

```
var str = 'Twas the night before Xmas...';
var newstr = str.replace(/xmas/i, 'Christmas');
console.log(newstr);  // Twas the night before Christmas...
```

So you could do:

```
var str = 'sampleword';
var newstr = str.replace('sampleword', '');
```

And get your expected output.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me all the time.

Try the following:

```
var string = 'This is a word.';
var replacedstring = string.replace('word', 'sentence');
alert(replacedstring);
```

In the example i have use `string.replace('word', 'sentence');` for replacing a word.

In the string `This is a word.` word is the word that will be replaced with `sentence`.

And for jquery use this:

```
$("#string").val($("#stript").val().replace('word', 'sentence'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't absolutely need jQuery to accomplish this. Regular JavaScript will suffice as well:
https://jsfiddle.net/ot1jx61d/

```
var txtStr = document.getElementById("txtArea").value;
txtStr = txtStr.replace('sampleword', '');
document.getElementById("txtArea").innerHTML = txtStr;
```

or even...

```
document.getElementById("txtArea").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtArea").value.replace('sampleword', '');
```

In jQuery:
https://jsfiddle.net/9pwnm6rb/1/

```
$("#txtArea").val($("#txtArea").val().replace('sampleword', ''));
```